# Dynamic create input element through JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have written the code to create text field dynamically. It should create element according to the number that I fill in form's text field, but it is creating only one field. It should create 5 text fields if put 5 in  form. What is the problem?
Here is the code:

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
<!--Hide from old browsers
function createtext(){
var i=0;
var len1=document.getElementById('s');
var len2=len1.value;
for(i;i<len2;i++)
{
var el= new Array();;
el[i]=document.createElement('input');
el[i].type='text';
el[i].name='text'+i;
el[i].size = 10;
document.f1.appendChild(el[i]);
var mybr=document.createElement('<br>');
document.appendChild(mybr);
}
}
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY >
<form action="" method="get" name="f1">
<input type="text" id="s" name="s" value="" onChange="createtext()" >
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var mybr=document.createElement('<br>');    
document.appendChild(mybr);
```

should be

```
var mybr=document.createElement('br');    
document.f1.appendChild(mybr);
```